# dynamically choose the right template to use

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am going through a list of posts and choose the right html handlebar template depending on the type of content( image, text, twitter post). This becomes rather ugly with more and more template types though:

```
<template name="postItem">

{{#if isType "image"}}
    {{#if isSinglePost}}
        {{>postImageSingle}}
    {{else}}
        {{>postImage}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
{{#if isType "rich"}}
    {{#if isSinglePost}}
        {{>postRichSingle}}
    {{else}}
        {{>postRich}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
{{#if isType "video"}}
    {{#if isSinglePost}}
        {{>postRichSingle}}
    {{else}}
        {{>postRich}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
{{#if isType "file"}}
    {{#if isMimeType "audio/wav"}}
        {{>postAudio}}
    {{else}}
        {{>postFile}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
{{#if isType "link"}}
    {{#if isProviderName this "Twitter"}}
        {{>postTwitter}}
    {{else}}
        {{#if isSinglePost }}
            {{>postLinkSingle}}
        {{else}}
            {{>postLink}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}

{{#if isType "preview"}}
    {{>postPreview}}
{{/if}}

{{#if isType "photo"}}
    {{>postImage}}
{{/if}}

</template>
```

It would be better to move the logic into a helper function, but what I struggle with is how I could return the name of the template to use from the helper function.

```
{{>getTemplateName}}

Template.postItem.getTemplateName = function () {
    return postImage;
};
```

but this of course gives me:

```
Exception from Deps recompute: Error: No such template 'getTemplateName'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{> template}}` syntax is for inserting templates only, while for helpers you use `{{helper}}`, without the angle bracket `>`. Remove the bracket from your helper invocation, and render the needed subtemplate inside the helper:

```
Template.postItem.getTemplateName = function() {
    return new Handlebars.safeString(Template.postImage());

};
```

Comment: after playing around with this suggestion, I think it needs to be passed the context with `this`: `return new Handlebars.safeString(Template.postImage(this))`. thanks for the help put me on the right track.